# How to identify additional resources when pivoting

Tags: network, proxy, network-scanners, reconnaissance, proxychains

I'm currently looking into pivoting when performing network penetration tests, but I'm having issues with reconnaissance.

Given the scenario I have full control over a server, which is publicly available and connected to an internal, non-routable, network. I want to extend my test to the internal network.

I start an SSH server on the server between the networks and connect to it from my attacking machine, creating a local socks proxy. Then I use `proxychains` to tunnel the traffic of my tools, like `nmap`.

Usually I start off with doing an `nmap` ping scan, to get a rough idea of the network, but from what I've learned ICMP packets are not supported by `proxychains`.

In the illustration below, the green circle represents the publicly accessible network and the the blue cloud represents the internal network.

I can ping any public machine, to get a rough idea of the network (green arrows), but I can't ping the internal network through the proxychains/ssh tunnel (pink arrow).

A first idea, was to use the `arp` table on the server connected to both networks, but that doesn't hold much information.

How do I gather information about the internal network?

[image: Mockup of the situation]

Comment: It sounds like you are running nmap on your machine and tunnelling the requests - why aren't you running it on that machine you can connect to, and just sending the output back to yourself?

Comment: That's an fair point and a somewhat viable solution. For this I have to install nmap on the server, which isn't an optimal solution. I figured there has to be a method to identify hosts on the target network, solely by using the server as a proxy.

Comment: Okay. You don't need to use icmp then... :-)

Comment: From what I can tell proxychains doesn't support ICMP, nor UDP. What other proxying solution could I use? I could - theoretically speaking - install a VPN server on the target and use the VPN, but that's as an even less attractive solution than performing the scans on the server.